# Renewal function strictly subadditive

Tags: stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

The question can be stated very simply as:

When is a renewal function $U$ not only subadditive ($U(x+y) \leq U(x) + U(y)$), but strictly subadditive (<)? Or, in other words, when is the renewal function additive, i.e. $U(x+y) = U(x) + U(y)$?

For a proof of the subadditive nature of a renewal function I found in [Daley](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176995434):

[image]

Question 2: Are there always $x,y$ such that $U(x+y) < U(x) + U(y)$?

Comment: It would help to know what $U(t)$ means, precisely. If it is the (sample path)  number of renewals up to time $t$ then it cannot be strictly subadditive:  If the first renewal is at time $t=3$ then $U(1+1) = U(1) + U(1) = 0$. (Edit: But, this cannot be the definition of $U(t)$ because it is not subadditive under this def, either). Perhaps it is supposed to be the _expectation_ of the number of renewals up to time $t$.

Comment: But of course this again does not work because we could have renewals that appear every 1 time unit, with prob 1, with the first appearing at time $t=1$, and then neither the sample path nor the expectation of the number of renewals up to time $t$ is subadditive (the expectation and sample path coincide in this example).

Comment: Thanks. For a random walk $S$ starting at $0$ with nonnegative increments define the renewal function $U(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(S_n \leq t)$. Then $U(0)= 1$ and if the first renewal is at time $t=3$, then $U(1+1) = 1 \leq U(1)+U(1) = 2$. I hope this helps..

Comment: @Michael Generally the "renewal function" is the expected number of renewals up to time $t$.